# GAP WreathProduct with fixed points

Tags: group-theory, gap, wreath-product

Gap always takes the domain of a permutation group to be the set of points moved by its elements. The documentation of `WreathProduct` thus includes this comment explaining how form the wreath product between permutation groups whose domains include fixed points:

"If fixed points are desired the wreath product $G \wr T$ has to be formed with a transitive overgroup $T$ of $P$ and then the pre-image of $P$ under the projection $G \wr T \rightarrow T$ has to be taken."

Can someone more well versed in GAP than me demonstrate how to do this in practice? Say e.g.
I want to compute `WreathProduct(Group([(1,2)(3)]), Group([(1,2)]))`, i.e. I want to compute the wreath product as if the first group had domain $\{1,2,3\}$ instead $\{1,2\}$. How do I do that?

Comment: From your description in the second paragraph, it sounds as though you want to allow the second group $P$ in the wreath product to have fixed points, which makes sense because that affects the isomorphism class of the resulting wreath product. But then in your example, you appear to want the first group to have a fixed point, which makes less sense, because that would result in the resulting group having two extra fixed points, which would not affect its isomorphism class. Please clarify.

Comment: @DerekHolt. I suspect he really wants the permutation isomorphism class with fixed points -- e.g. for constructing actions on combinatorial objects.

Comment: @ahulpke: Yes that's right, I was confused as to what the quote from the manual was trying to tell me so I probably mixed those two things up in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the wreath product of a trasitive overgroup (in your example $S_3$) by your second factor, and then take the group generated by the image of your embedded group $G$, together with (the image of) $T$:

```
gap> G:=Group((1,2));;
gap> S:=SymmetricGroup(3);
Sym( [ 1 .. 3 ] )
gap> T:=Group((1,2));;
gap> WS:=WreathProduct(S,T);
Group([ (1,2,3), (1,2), (4,5,6), (4,5), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6) ])
gap> Gemb:=Image(Embedding(WS,1),G);
Group([ (1,2) ])
gap> Temb:=Image(Embedding(WS,3),T);  # 3=1+LargestMovedPoint(T);
Group([ (1,4)(2,5)(3,6) ])
gap> W:=ClosureGroup(Gemb,Temb);
Group([ (1,2), (1,4)(2,5)(3,6) ])
gap> Size(W);
8
```

You could do analogously if $T$ is not transitive (though then you would take embeddings of $G$ for every orbit of $T$.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you.